# Intellij Idea Spring boot dev-tools with liveloader extension error on creating bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-boot-devtools

I am trying to make my Java application automatically updating after making changes. When I change html or css files auto updating content is working perfectly but when i'm changing the java class my project rebuild automatically but throws an error. When I stop and rerun my application in ide by clicking it everything is working.

Im using intellij Idea ide and I changed here 2 setting

In menu shift+cltr+a in registry I enabled allow compile when running

In build setting I enabled auto build

I will be very thankful for every help.

Error which I get

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-07-09 01:09:37.490 ERROR 212 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter': Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.LinkageError-->loader (instance of jdk/internal/loader/ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader): attempted duplicate class definition for name: "org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/HttpMessageConverters$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d90bff9"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:673) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:371) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:574) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:497) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-20180706.150128-217.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-20180706.150128-217.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-20180706.150128-217.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-20180706.150128-217.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-20180706.150128-217.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1222) [spring-boot-2.1.0.BUILD-20180706.150128-217.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.zerg.myWebsite.MyWebsiteApplication.main(MyWebsiteApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.0.BUILD-20180706.150038-217.jar:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter': Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.LinkageError-->loader (instance of jdk/internal/loader/ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader): attempted duplicate class definition for name: "org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/HttpMessageConverters$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d90bff9"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:252) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1286) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1188) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1091) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1060) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:665) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.LinkageError-->loader (instance of jdk/internal/loader/ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader): attempted duplicate class definition for name: "org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/HttpMessageConverters$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d90bff9"
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.buildLazyResolutionProxy(ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.getLazyResolutionProxyIfNecessary(ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.java:52) ~[spring-context-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1057) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1278) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:497) ~[spring-beans-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.LinkageError-->loader (instance of jdk/internal/loader/ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader): attempted duplicate class definition for name: "org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/HttpMessageConverters$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d90bff9"
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:502) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:359) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:582) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:106) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:104) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:130) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:315) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:569) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:416) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:58) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of jdk/internal/loader/ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader): attempted duplicate class definition for name: "org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/HttpMessageConverters$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1d90bff9"
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.System$2.defineClass(System.java:2131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.defineClass(MethodHandles.java:964) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:498) ~[spring-core-5.1.0.BUILD-20180708.121145-240.jar:5.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

My pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.zerg</groupId>
    <artifactId>myWebsite</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>myWebsite</name>
    <description>My website project.</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>10</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

My application.properties file

```
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webproject?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin

#Hikari will use the above plus the following to setup connection pooling
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=20
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=SpringBootJPAHikariCP
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=2000000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000

spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

My SpringBootApplication file

```
package com.zerg.myWebsite;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class MyWebsiteApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyWebsiteApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My Controller class which I am testing to change

```
package com.zerg.myWebsite.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;


@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home(@RequestParam(name = "DevTools", required = false, defaultValue = "Testing!") String name,
                       Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        String test = "test liveloader";
        model.addAttribute("getString", test);
        return "home.html";
    }

}
```

My html file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Testing Spring Devtools!</h1>
<p th:text="'SpringFramework, ' + ${name} + '!'"></p>
<p th:text="'SpringFramework, ' + ${getString} + '!'"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

In older version of spring-boot 2.0.3 the html auto updating is working but when I change java class everything is building amd compiling fine but my web page in chrome doesnt load it gives error

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Jul 09 15:29:48 CEST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

When I change something in SpringBootApplication class and save changes it builds automatically and everything is working my html page shows in chrome but when i change other java classes it gives error shown above.

Comment: Possible bug in Spring: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16902

Comment: I changed to older version of spring boot 2.0.3 and now when I change java class it is building automatically without errors and my page in chrome is refreshing but showing error: Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. (404).